# ocamltop like 'trace' directive in ocamldebug

Tags: debugging, ocaml

Is there a ocamltop's `trace` directive equivalent in ocamldebug ?

I need to use ocamldebug because my project has a few dozens of files and loading them into ocamltop hard(load order matters etc.). With ocamldebug, I can just give the compiled file and it works.

For now I'm using some custom identity functions to trace function calls in ocamldebug. Ie. I have several identity functions:

```
let id_some_fun_1 a p1 p2 = a p1 p2
let id_some_fun_2 a p = a p
```

Then in my code, I'm wrapping the function I want to trace with this functions, and then I'm setting breakpoints.

As you may have guessed, this is way harder than just running `#trace some_fun_1`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `#trace` is a reliable debugging tool anyway, but note that the limitations of the toplevel you mentioned can be overcome: you can just put the `#load` directives in the right order in a new `top.ml` file, and just use `#use "top.ml";;` in the toplevel when you want to load your code.